# How to disable entity caching to Redis only for a certain controller action?

Tags: php, symfony, redis, doctrine, symfony4

I have a controller action that performs some heavy work on the database/entities. While profiling I noticed that a lot of time is wasted by the caching layer that writes to Redis. Is there any way to disable the second level cache to Redis only for this specific route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this:

Extend `Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider` class and override `save` and `saveMultiple` methods. Use a static boolean variable on your class to control saving to cache:

```
// Your custom class that extends the DoctrineProvider
public function save($id, $data, $lifeTime = 0)
{
    if (static::$enableWriting === false) {
        return false;
    }

    return parent::save($id, $data, $lifeTime);
}


// packages/doctrine.yaml
services:
    doctrine.result_cache_provider:
        class: App\Cache\ResultCacheDoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable caching or change per Query, e.g. with [`useQueryCache()`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php#L441) or [`useResultCache()`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L537).

In your repository you can use `$this->createQueryBuilder()` to build the query. Alternatively the entity manager provides a `createQuery()`-method which takes a DQL-string. On the resulting query object from either of these methods, before calling `getResult()` on the Query-object, you can call these methods.